# Подскажите как мигрировать с Vue3 на Vue2

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, css-animation

Хотел спросить как изменить код с Vue3 на Vue2 и сохранить его работоспособность.

```
const appData = {
  setup() {
    const circles = Vue.ref([{
        id: 0,
        x: 50,
        y: 50,
        d: 100,
        color: "#409de4",
        lines: [1, 2], // id окружности(ей), с которой соединена текущая
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        x: 250,
        y: 250,
        d: 100,
        color: "#1a7a3f",
        lines: [3],
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        x: 450,
        y: 30,
        d: 100,
        color: "#35495e",
        lines: [],
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        x: 550,
        y: 200,
        d: 100,
        color: "#f4cd00",
        lines: [0],
      },
    ]);

    /*
     * В вычислительном свойстве, при подготовке линий, соединяющих между собой, указанные выше, точки
     * определяем углы поворотов каждой из этих линий, чтобы узнать координаты
     * точек пересечения линии и окружностей (это нужно чтобы отрисовать окружности - коннекторы)
     *
     */
    const lines = Vue.computed(() => {
      return circles.value.reduce((acc, circleEl) => {
        const lines = circleEl.lines.map((b) => {
          const radius = circleEl.d / 2; // радиус окружности
          const x1 = circleEl.x + radius + 5; // абсцисса начала линии
          const y1 = circleEl.y + radius + 5; // ордината начала линии
          const x2 = circles.value[b].x + circles.value[b].d / 2 + 5; // абсцисса конца линии
          const y2 = circles.value[b].y + circles.value[b].d / 2 + 5; // ордината конца линии

          const calcAngle = (x, y) =>
            x > 0 && y < 0 ?
            Math.PI / 2 + Math.atan(x / y) :
            x <= 0 && y < 0 ?
            Math.PI / 2 + Math.atan(x / y) :
            x > 0 && y >= 0 ?
            (3 * Math.PI) / 2 + Math.abs(Math.atan(x / y)) :
            x <= 0 && y >= 0 ?
            Math.PI + Math.abs(Math.atan(y / x)) :
            0;

          // угол для первой точки
          const ang = calcAngle(x1 - x2, y2 - y1);

          // угол для второй точки
          const ang2 = calcAngle(x2 - x1, y1 - y2);

          return {
            line: {
              x1,
              y1,
              x2,
              y2,
              // stroke: circleEl.color,
            },
            ang,
            ang2,
            colorFrom: circles.value[b].color,
            colorTo: circleEl.color,
            cx: radius * Math.cos(ang) + x2, // абсцисса первой точки
            cy: radius * Math.sin(ang) + y2, // ордината первой точки
            cx2: radius * Math.cos(ang2) + x1, // абсцисса второй точки
            cy2: radius * Math.sin(ang2) + y1, // ордината второй точки
          };
        });
        return acc.concat(lines);
      }, []);
    });

    const addCircle = () => {
      circles.value.push({
        id: circles.value.length,
        x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 500),
        y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 500),
        d: 100,
        color: `#${Math.floor(
                Math.random() * (999999 - 100000) + 100000
              )}`,
        lines: [Math.floor(Math.random() * circles.value.length)],
      });
    };

    return {
      circles,
      lines,
      addCircle,
    };
  },
};

const app = Vue.createApp(appData);

app.component("v-circle", {
  props: ["modelValue"],
  emits: ["update:modelValue"],
  setup(props, {
    emit
  }) {
    // ссылка на элемент, чтобы иметь возможность обращения к нему как к DOM элементу
    const el = Vue.ref(null);

    // флаг перемещения (если он true - меняем координаты текущего элемента)
    const drag = Vue.ref(false);
    // позиция текущего элемента
    const pos = Vue.reactive({
      x: props.modelValue.x,
      y: props.modelValue.y,
    });
    // функция для события перемещения элемента, путем изменения его координат
    const move_handler = (e) => {
      if (drag.value) {
        pos.x = e.pageX - el.value.offsetWidth / 2;
        pos.y = e.pageY - el.value.offsetHeight / 2;
        // передаем измененные координаты в родительский компонент
        emit("update:modelValue", {
          ...props.modelValue,
          x: pos.x,
          y: pos.y,
        });
      }
    };

    const toggleDrag = () => {
      drag.value = !drag.value;
    };

    Vue.onMounted(() => {
      // вешаем обработчик на событие перемещения курсора мыши,
      // чтобы иметь возможность изменить координаты элемента
      window.addEventListener("mousemove", move_handler);
    });

    return {
      el,
      pos,
      drag,
      toggleDrag,
    };
  },
  template: `
      <div ref="el" :class="['circle']" :style="{background: modelValue.color, position:'absolute', top: modelValue.y + 'px', left: modelValue.x + 'px', width: modelValue.d + 'px', height: modelValue.d + 'px'}" @mousedown="toggleDrag" @mouseup="toggleDrag">
          <slot>
        </slot>
      </div>
      `,
});
app.mount("#app");
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
  border: 5px solid white;
  color: white;
  font-size: 45px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  user-select: none;
}
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button type="button" @click="addCircle">Add random circle</button>
  <div class="relative">
    <template v-for="(circle,keyCircle) in circles">
          <v-circle v-model="circles[keyCircle]"> {{keyCircle}} </v-circle>

          <template v-if="lines">
            <svg
              style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: -1"
              width="100vw"
              height="100vh"
            >
              <template v-for="(line, keyLine) in lines">
                <defs>
                  <linearGradient
                    :id="`gr_${keyCircle}_${keyLine}`"
                    v-bind="{...line.line}"
                    gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                  >
                    <stop :stop-color="line.colorTo" offset="0" />
                    <stop :stop-color="line.colorFrom" offset="1" />
                  </linearGradient>
                </defs>
                <line
                  v-bind="{...line.line}"
                  stroke-width="10px"
                  stroke-linecap="round"
                  stroke-dasharray="1 15"
                  :stroke="`url(#gr_${keyCircle}_${keyLine})`"
                />
                <circle
                  :cx="line.cx"
                  :cy="line.cy"
                  r="15"
                  :fill="line.colorFrom"
                />
                <circle
                  :cx="line.cx2"
                  :cy="line.cy2"
                  r="15"
                  :fill="line.colorTo"
                />
              </template>
    </svg>
    </template>
    </template>
  </div>
</div>
Вернуться к сообщению
```

Comment: никак только изучать документацию

Comment: целесообразность таких действий тоже сомнительна

Comment: спасибо за отличную рекомендацию